# How to resolve the error in launching git

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, git

I have installed the latest `git`(version 2.25.0) in Windows. However, I got an error while I am executing any of the git commands either in `Powershell` or in `Command Prompt`.

After executing the git command, the terminal produces :

> Error launching git: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete

I have already uninstalled and reinstalled the software and restarted the system after installation. Can anyone help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, you may need to resize your page file.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: Try performing steps from my answer, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I am facing the same issue still

Comment: Does your C drive has enough free space?

Comment: Yes, it has about 300GB free

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208171/discussion-between-pavithra-and-shubham-namdeo).

Answer (score 1):

AS per my understanding error here seems to be with the `Windows` page file and not `Git`.

Try the following steps below to resize the page file.

> 1. Start, Control Panel, System
> 2. The system properties applet will appear, select the advanced tab
> 3. In the performance tab, click settings
> 4. The performance dialog will appear, click the advanced tab click the change button.
> 5. You will now (assuming that you are a local admin) be able to increase the size of you virtual memory.
> 6. Change the paging size and click set.
> 7. Click OK
> 8. Click OK
> 9. Click OK
> 10. At this point, the machine may need to re-start.

Reference: [Paging file is too small for this operation to complete](https://communities.bentley.com/products/hydraulics___hydrology/w/hydraulics_and_hydrology__wiki/13358/paging-file-is-too-small-for-this-operation-to-complete)